# Automatically Log-in an user after they type the correct credentials

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

**I want to remove the log-in button entirely from my app's login process.**

The moment the user fills in their log-in credentials the app will automatically log the user in and redirect them to the main screen / activity.

I am using Firebase and Kotlin so it has to be possible using these two.

What the app should do is:

1. Log-in Activity waits for the user to arrive at the log-in screen
2. Log-in Activity waits for the user to fill up the e-mail address
3. Log-in Activity waits for the user to fill up the password
4. After they stop typing in the password field there would be a one second delay before the Log-in Activity checks back with Firebase to verify if the credentials are correct and if they are it will log in the user, if not it returns a log-in failed message or whatever.

Is this possible? And if the answer is yes, how could I do that?

*Note: This should only happen for the log-in screen, the sign-up process will not use this feature as it would be confusing to the user.*

Comment: Well the steps you have described are obviously possible, but it doesn't seem like a great user experience.

Comment: I do understand that this is an unusual concept, perhaps even silly but I'd like to experiment with it. I'm curious to see how such an experience would feel like. If it feels weird I can always switch back to the "industry standard".

Comment: Which part are you stuck with? Your steps seem like a simple timer which gets reset whenever a character is typed, along with some empty input checking etc. Or have I mis-interpreted what you're trying to do?

Comment: I haven't started working on setting it up yet, at the moment the process works normally through the log-in button. I asked in here because first of all I wanted to see if something like that would even be possible and also what suggestions I'd get. Your suggestion seems very good, I'll look into trying it out and see where it goes.

Comment: Definitely possible, you've already pretty much answered your own questions by detailing the steps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, it isn't that hard to figure out the logic behind the process it's just that I wanted to make sure I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try implmenting the "afterTextChanged" -

```
   password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {



 @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

  @Override    
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
   int count, int after) {
  }

  @Override    
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int before, int count) {
 
  }
 });
```